# Laravel query builder not getting results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table with the following columns: `model_id, starts and end`

I'm looking to run a query tath finds all the rows that matches the provided model_id and have a start bigger and end lower that the provided code. Example: if the provided code is 15 and the model_id is 5 I should get all the rows that have model_id = 5 and start >= 15 and end <= 15.

This is th query I'm working with:

```
DB::table('generations')->where([['model_id', '=', 1],['starts', '>=', '1998'], ['end', '<=', '1998']])->get();
```

I transformed this to the raw sql but the returned sql query does not get any results too.

I'm using Laravel 5.7

Rows with model_id = 1;

[image]

Comment: Did you try the run the SQL you want first and then covert that to the equivalent eloquent query? Cause that should work, at least the columns ``starts`` and ``end`` are not declared as numeric data type.

Comment: Yes I've tried writing down my own raw sql bus still don't work and does not get results. I checked and model_id, starts and end are all int fields

Comment: Can you share the row with the model_id = 1 from the table?

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: Okay, we maybe missing something, first make sure ``SELECT * FROM generations WHERE  model_id = 1 AND starts => 1990  AND end <= 2009`` is returning your rows, second log you eloquent query and compare and share,  https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging

Comment: ig I run your sql query returns both the 2 existing rows for model_id 1 but starts and end fields must be compared with the same code in this case should be SELECT * FROM generations WHERE  model_id = 1 AND starts => 2009  AND end <= 2009 this should return 1 row but returns 0 rows.

Comment: Is because you don't have a value in the start column that matches that, pay attention to values in the column, So the be able to finish the help here, what is what you really want to filter? Values between those column, or any value in range of those columns (starts, end)

Comment: any row that matches the same model_id and have starts equal or bigger than the code provided and at the same time the end column has a value equal or smaller that the code provided. So the codde provided must be between the starts and end columns.

Comment: if the code is 1995 I should get the row that says starts 1990 and end 2001

Comment: You already have that ``SELECT * FROM generations WHERE  model_id = 1 AND starts => 1995 AND end <= 1995``

Comment: this query it's returning 0 results and I don't know why

Comment: Your columns are being misplaced, you logic  should be ``SELECT * FROM generations WHERE  model_id = 1  AND starts <= 1995  AND ends >= 1995``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic's order is the problem.

```php
DB::table('generations')->where('model_id', '=', 1)->where('start', '<=', 1995)->where('end' , '>=', 1995)->get();
```

Learn more in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses).